# Simple spark ignite job cannot save data, get error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ignite

I have the following Spark Ignite code:

```
package com.knoldus

import org.apache.ignite.spark.{IgniteRDD, IgniteContext}
import org.apache.ignite.configuration._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import my.test._

object RDDProducer extends App {
  println("aaa")
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkIgnitePro")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
  val ic = new IgniteContext(sc, "/mnt/ignite/config/node-config.xml",true)
  println("bbb")
  val sharedRDD = ic.fromCache[String, my.test.MyPoint]("myCache2")

  val myMap = Map("1" -> new MyPoint(1,2), "2" -> new MyPoint(3,4))
  sharedRDD.savePairs(sc.parallelize(myMap.toSeq)
      .map{case (id, p) => {
          (id, p)
      }})
  println("ccc")
}
```

/mnt/ignite/config/default-config.xml has content:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
            <property name="name" value="myCache2"/>
            <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
            <property name="queryEntities">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                        <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.String"/>
                        <property name="valueType" value="my.test.MyPoint"/>
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

/mnt/ignite/config/node-config.xml has content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
       <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.wrapRefArray(java.lang.Object[])'
    at com.knoldus.RDDProducer$.delayedEndpoint$com$knoldus$RDDProducer$1(SparkIgnite.scala:22)
    at com.knoldus.RDDProducer$delayedInit$body.apply(SparkIgnite.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
```

I'm trying to store pairs of key (String) and value (MyPoint) into Ignite's shared Spark RDD. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Which version of Ignite? Which version of Spark?

Comment: I was using Spark 3.3.2 Compiled for Scala 1.12 and Ignite 2.14. And I compiled the jar that I submit to spark with Scala 1.13. Now I replaced Spark 3.3.2 with the version compiled for Scala 2.13.8, but I get the well known java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable. I don't know how to solve this dependencies hell. I'm thinking of compiling Spark 3.3.2 from source with Scala 2.13.0.

Comment: I found a version that works out well for all: my jar, spark and spark-ignite - Scala 2.12.15. But I was unable to use latest Scala 3 or 2.13 because of the issue in the post or the issue in the comment above or other issues.